# jsoup get data from website

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using Java jsoup to get the "Last" price from http://www.aastocks.com/en/ltp/rtquote.aspx?symbol=00055&process=y

My code:

```
String price = null;
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.aastocks.com/tc/ltp/rtquote.aspx?symbol=00055").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(5*1000).get();  // s
Elements answerers = document.select(".C.font28.bold ");
price = answerer.text();
        }

 System.out.println(price);
```

But it returns:

```
run:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please help

Comment: Most probably your element selector is wrong. How should we know? Have you checked an element with this class/name/... exist?

Comment: so what select should I use?

Comment: what I am doing is down all stock "Last" price to my computer

Comment: price = answerer.text() ? or price = answerers.text(); ?. Later one is correct I guess

Answer (score 0):

To get e.g. the CSS Selector with Firefox:

- right-click on the Element of which you want to get the Selector.
- Choose "inspect" or "inspect with Firebug".
- Then right-click the selected source and choose "Copy CSS Path".

You would get this CSS Path:

html body div#AAMainMaster div.floatL div.frame_w.floatL div div.c_w div.div-container div.RContentBox.floatL form#aspnetForm div.div-container div.floatL div.div-container.bmp-s1 div#rtQuoteRightContent.floatL div.div-container table.tb-s4 tbody tr td.DR.bold

Hope this helps

regards